# Placing selected rows without duplicates

Tags: php

I'm selecting some values from a database (basically quiz questions) and I'm trying to place each question in a header with its input values.
However my syntax for `$row[0]` is giving me duplicates. The thing is for each question I have the same answers: 0-1-2-3-4.

My code to create this section once:

```
<li>
    <h3>'$row[0]'</h3>
    <input type='radio' name='question-1-answers' id='question-1-answers-A' value='A' />
    <label for='question-1-answers-A'>A) Computer Styled Sections </label>
    <input type='radio' name='question-1-answers' id='question-1-answers-B' value='B' />
    <label for='question-1-answers-B'>B) Cascading Style Sheets</label>
</li>
```

Such as all the questions appearing in  and the answers beneath it:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT question FROM questions WHERE type='$type'")) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $quiz="<form action='' method='post' id='quiz'>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <h3>'$row[0]'</h3>
                    <input type='radio' name='question-1-answers' id='question-1-answers-A' value='A' />
                    <label for='question-1-answers-A'>A) Computer Styled Sections </label>
                    <input type='radio' name='question-1-answers' id='question-1-answers-B' value='B' />
                    <label for='question-1-answers-B'>B) Cascading Style Sheets</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h3>'$row[0]'</h3>
                    <input type='radio' name='question-2-answers' id='question-2-answers-A' value='A' />
                    <label for='question-2-answers-A'>A) 2001</label>
                    <input type='radio' name='question-2-answers' id='question-2-answers-B' value='B' />
                    <label for='question-2-answers-B'>B) 1998</label>
                </li>
            </ol>
            <input type='submit' value='Submit Quiz' />
        </form>";
     echo $quiz;
    }
    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}
```

Comment: I'm a tad confused because, you are using the same variables twice, The `$row[0]` Are both used in question 1 and question 2. So of course they'll be duplicate?

Comment: @Epodax yes i know, because i don't know what's the correct syntax to place each question once.. And i looked for an answer however couldn't find it

Comment: It's fairly simple, each run through the while loop will print one question. Here you are telling it to print the same question twice. The issue lies (with from what I can see), with that you have static values / ID's, instead of writing `-1-` in your name and id, replace it with `" . $i . "` and then just outside of your while loop add a `$i = 1;` and also at the end of your loop add `$i++`; (and then delete the second `<li></li>`

Comment: @Epodax any idea how to prevent the submit button from repeating under each question. And instead being one submit for all the questions?

Comment: See @RamRaider 's answer, it'll do the trick for you, also I'd suggest you find some tutorials and learn.

Comment: @Epodax any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a guide might I suggest something like this?

```
<?php
    if ( $result = $mysqli->query( "SELECT question, answerA,answerB FROM questions WHERE type='$type'" ) ) {

        /* rather than string concatenation use an array */
        $html=array();

        $html[]="
        <form action='' method='post' id='quiz'>
            <ol>";

        $counter=1;

        /* add a question and associated answers for each row */
        while( $row = $result->fetch_array() ) {

            /* Fetch recordset fields into vars */
            $question=$row['question'];
            $answerA=$row['answerA'];
            $answerB=$row['answerB'];

            $html[]="
                <h3>Question {$counter}: {$question}</h3>
                <li>
                    <input type='radio' name='question-{$counter}-answers' id='question-{$counter}-answers-A' value='A' />
                    <label for='question-{$counter}-answers-A'>A) {$answerA} </label>
                    <input type='radio' name='question-{$counter}-answers' id='question-{$counter}-answers-B' value='B' />
                    <label for='question-{$counter}-answers-B'>B) {$answerB} </label>
                </li>";

            $counter++;
        }

        $html[]="
            </ol>
            <input type='submit' value='Submit Quiz' />
        </form>";

        echo implode( PHP_EOL, $html );
        $result->close();
    }

?>
```

Comment: @RamiRaider sorry man i got this error :  Call to a member function close() on boolean in..Why ?

Comment: i fixed it..Just if you don't mind me asking just a logical question. If i have for each question the same answer (1-2-3-4-5) it's necessary to place it into my database?

Comment: The call to `$result->close()` was outwith the `if( $result... )` clause which would have caused that error most likely if the query failed. Not necessary to put the answers in the db @dan - I didn't know how they were derived and that would be a standard way of doing it - so I made an assumption!

Comment: i was just asking.. Anyway thank you for your help, i really appreciate it

Comment: are you still available?

Comment: I'm still sat at the laptop

Comment: is it possible to open a chat conv for a minute please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86974/discussion-between-dan-and-ramraider).